# Mongodb - Can you update two values, with a javascript Object Literal Property Value Shorthand?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So I want to do this:

```
DB.update(_id, {$set: {myUpdate, updated: new Date()}});
```

But its not working as intended. When I run that, I literally get a new field called "myUpdate". If I run this version of the code instead:

```
DB.update(_id, {$set: myUpdate});
```

It starts to work fine. Where all the keys and values in myUpdate will be applied to the document. But at the same time I want to update the 'updated' value too.

Is there a way I can perhaps combine these two queries?

```
DB.update(_id, {$set: myUpdate});
DB.update(_id, {$set: {updated: new Date()}});
```

edit:

Heres my `myUpdate` object. I am using it so its more convenient to update the fields that I need.

```
let myUpdate= {};
if (args.shortName) {
  myUpdate.shortName = args.shortName;
}
if (args.fullName) {
  myUpdate.fullName = args.fullName;
}
```

Comment: how does your my update look like?

Comment: let myUpdate= {};
    if (args.shortName) {
      myUpdate.shortName = args.shortName;
    }
    if (args.fullName) {
      myUpdate.fullName = args.fullName;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add the updated to your `myUpdate` object and then perform update query, as follows:

```
myUpdate.updated = new Date();
DB.update(_id, {$set: myUpdate});
```

Comment: Wow, why didn't I think of that